# En la variable de Instancia solo se guarda la "referencia" del objeto?

Tags: java, poo, heap

Cordial Saludo

Estos días he estado leyendo y desconocía que los objetos se almacenaban en otra memoria diferente a la **Stack**, acá surge mi duda ¿la variable con la cual instancie el objeto solo contiene la "referencia" del objeto?

```
Doctor myDoctor = new Doctor();
```

Yo lo comprendo de la siguiente manera: La variable myDoctor esta almacenada en la memoria **stack**, pero esta variable solo contiene las coordenadas del objeto y en la memoria ***Heap*** estará el objeto en si con todos sus datos

Me equivoco?

Gracias :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: por favor, recuerda aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron.. esa es la forma de decir gracias aca en SO

Comment: En la variable `myDoctor` se guarda la referencia del objeto, sí, es correcto. La "referencia" no es mas que el identificador único del objeto y esto es algo que la misma JVM se encarga de asignar. Es más, si pruebas otros lenguajes como C++, ese "identificador" es simplemente una *dirección de memoria*.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo general, el **stack** almacena variables *LOCALES* (declaradas en el método en el que te encuentras) así como *referencias a objetos* (como sería el caso de myDoctor, que no es más que una referencia al objeto), además también se usa para "llevar la cuenta" de los métodos que se han llamado y sus retornos, de ahí el famoso "stack overflow" cuando se hacen demasiadas llamadas recursivas por ejemplo.

El **Heap** por otro lado, se utiliza generalmente para almacenar los *objetos* y también las *variables de instancia* que contengan.

En google se puede encontrar mucha [información](http://www.javahispano.org/certificacion/2011/9/27/stack-y-heap.html) al respecto, si bien algunas fuentes son bastante antiguas, la información sigue siendo válida pues esto no ha cambiado en Java!